# Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:network-common:4.0.0.302

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project .
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':mishop2client:GooglePlayDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:network-common:4.0.0.302.
     Required by:
         project :mishop2client
      > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:network-common:4.0.0.302.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/thelasterstar/maven/com/huawei/hms/network-common/4.0.0.302/network-common-4.0.0.302.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/thelasterstar/maven/com/huawei/hms/network-common/4.0.0.302/network-common-4.0.0.302.pom'. Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
   > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:network-common:4.0.0.302.
     Required by:
         project :mishop2client > com.huawei.hms:network-grs:4.0.0.302
      > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:network-common:4.0.0.302.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/thelasterstar/maven/com/huawei/hms/network-common/4.0.0.302/network-common-4.0.0.302.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/thelasterstar/maven/com/huawei/hms/network-common/4.0.0.302/network-common-4.0.0.302.pom'. Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
```

This error is always reported during the integration of the Push Kit. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is recommended that you integrate the [latest version of the Push Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-app-version-0000001074227861?ha_source=hms1). Currently, the latest version is **6.1.0.300**.
2. You are advised to check the network configuration.This error occurs because the Maven cannot be downloaded. The main reason is that the network is poor or restricted. For example, a firewall does not allow you to access the Huawei website.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven address seems not right in your log, pls replace the maven to huawei's repository and it is recommended that you put the address in the last position:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()    
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
}
```